# "make rails" giving syntax errors in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Every time I run **"make rails"** I get syntax errors and warnings within my terminal.

I'm using **ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin18.0]** because the project I'm working on mandates it, but I can update if needed.

We are currently using a legacy rails site as one of the users in the comments pointed out. This led to the find that we are our project would need to be run on ruby 2.3.0 as SOLR doesn't support the newer versions in our project. Furthermore, running `bundle install` also helps to resolve dependencies of older projects.

*This is what I get when I **make rails***:

```
Ahans-MacBook-Pro:app ahansabharwal$ make rails

POSTGRES starting
pg_ctl -D ./db/development.pg -l ./db/development.pg/postgres.log start
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
Connection to localhost port 5432 [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!

SOLR starting
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2097: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2103: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2142: warning: else without rescue is useless
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2093: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2097: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2103: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2138: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2142: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/ahansabharwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@project/gems/sass-3.7.2/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2920: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
.
. (similar syntax errors)
.
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
make[1]: *** [solr-force-start] Error 1
make: *** [solr] Error 2
```

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: @anothermh understood, thanks. Updated.

Comment: What version of OSX are you running, and can you run `rails server`?

Comment: @nzajt I'm running OSX 10.14.3. If I run `rails server`, I get the same type of error.

Comment: @muistooshort tried `rvm install ruby-2.4.2`, and if I `make rails` now I get: `An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: @muistooshort UPDATE: i fixed the eventmachine issue and now I'm getting `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer` when I try `make rails`

Comment: I had a similar issue on 10.14.3 with a legacy rails site, I had to remove my old version of ruby and then reinstall it. After you reinstall it you will need to run `bundle install` until you can get it to install all the gems, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by installing `ruby 2.3.0`, older versions aren't supported by SOLR. (2.6.0 onwards is not currently supported in our project)